# Body hasclass doesn´t work

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

so my code which should add a class to an element if the body has a certain class doesnt work. It looks like this:

```
if ($("body").hasClass("shifter-open")) {
    $(".scrollheader").addClass("hovered");
}
```

I think its because a Jquery code adds this class (shifter-open) to the body with this code:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("body").addClass("shifter shifter-active");

    $('.shifter-handle').click( function() {
        $("body").toggleClass("shifter-open", 1000);
    });
});
```

Is there a way to make my code work? and maybe combine these 2 codes into one?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to remove the class as well, just imitate exactly what the body is doing. You can toggle the class `hovered` on your `.scrollheader` just as the body is toggling its `shift-open` class.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("body").addClass("shifter shifter-active");

    $('.shifter-handle').click( function() {         //When shifter-handle is clicked
        $("body").toggleClass("shifter-open");       //Toggle "shifter-open" on the body
        $(".scrollheader").toggleClass("hovered");   //Toggle "hovered" on .scrollheader
    });
});
```

Additionally, the second parameter of [**toggleClass()**](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) takes a `boolean` that determines if the toggle should activate. Your second parameter of `1000` is permanently [**truthy**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy), so there is no reason at all to include it.

Comment: Thanks, its adding the hovered class, but its removing it again when the user isn´t hovering over it. Can we make it so it overwrites another jQuery script? This is the script that should be overwritten (I tried to do so by using a doesnothaveclass) `if (!$('body').hasClass('shifter-open')) {
var $header = $(".scrollheader");
$header.hover(function() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() == 0) {
    $header.addClass('hovered');
  }
},function() {
  if ($header.hasClass('hovered')) {
    $header.removeClass('hovered');
  }
});
}`

Comment: I don't know what you mean. In my example just change the scrollheader toggleClass to addClass...

Answer (score 0):

Your conditional :

```
if ($("body").hasClass("shifter-open")) {
    $(".scrollheader").addClass("hovered");
}
```

Is only going to be evaluated once unless you have a timeout or interval polling it. A better solution might be to combine those two sections into one. Such as:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("body").addClass("shifter shifter-active");

    $('.shifter-handle').click( function() {
        $("body").toggleClass("shifter-open", 1000);
        $(".scrollheader").toggleClass("hovered");
    });
});
```

Or something like that. You might also want to check the documentation for [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) because it doesn't appear to take an integer as a second parameter